# limit square-root proof

Tags: limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n} = \sqrt{a}$.

My attempt:

Assume $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ then there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n \geq N$

$$|a_n - a| < \epsilon$$

However for $n\geq N$

$$|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a| \leq (|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a|)^2 \leq |\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a||\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt a| = |a_n - a| < \epsilon$$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{a}$.

QED.

Is this proof correct? Did I miss any steps?

In addition, a general question: Why do we assume $\epsilon <$ some $M$ in some of these proofs? Although I am familiar with these proofs, I have never got an explanation as to why we cannot *always* let $\epsilon > 0$ without further restriction. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: How do you justify the step $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a| \leq (|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a|)^2$?

Comment: @Bumblebee Aren't all real numbers less than or equal to their square?

Comment: Think about numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Flewer47 Ohhhh my bad! So should I just let $\epsilon > 1$ then?

Comment: This would not complete the proof as $\epsilon$ has to be arbitrary, but just get rid of the first inequality and take square roots.

Comment: @AndrewMcMillan Ah I see. I made the corrections accordingly.

Comment: Consider $a=0$ seperately. Otherwise, you can use the facts that $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a|= \dfrac{|a_n-a|}{|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt a| }$ and $(a_n)$ is bounded (as it converges).

Comment: @Bumblebee So is the updated proof (in the post) still wrong then?

Comment: @Bumblebee I'll do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Correction:

Assume $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ then there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n \geq N$

$$|a_n - a| < \epsilon^2$$

However for $n\geq N$

$$(|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a|)^2 \leq |\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a||\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt a| = |a_n - a|$$

$$\implies |\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt a| \leq  \sqrt{|a_n - a|} < \epsilon$$

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{a}$.

QED.

Comment: +1. Looks good.